# Regex to remove __P() macro from C source files

Tags: regex, sed

I want to remove the macro __P() used in dozen of C source files, e.g:

```
char *x __P((char *, size_t,
        void *, size_t, int));
char *y __P((void *, const char *, int));
```

I'd like to use a regex to get the following:

```
char *x(char *, size_t,
        void *, size_t, int);
char *y(void *, const char *, int);
```

My problem is that the function declarations may contain a newline, and I want to remove the unnecessary braces.

Does anyone has a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex:** `(.*?)__P\((.*?)\);`

**Flags to use:**

- `g` for global search.
- `s` to allow dot matching newline.

**Replacement to do:** `\1\2;`

**Sed Command:** `sed 's/(.*?)__P\((.*?)\);/\1\2;/gs' file.c`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM4yR4/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Many thanks for the regex! I didn't know about `s`. Unfortunatly, it does not work in the command line:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems sed does not understand `s` as a pattern flag, but perl does:

```
perl -0777 -p -i -e 's/(.*?) __P\((.*?)\);/\1\2;/gs' file.c
```

Nevertheless, many thanks to noob for the correct regex!